# Magnetic properties

Tags: electromagnetism

I am talking about bluetooth headphones which have magnetic ear buds. We know same poles repel and opposite poles attract each other.

My question is:

Why bluetooth ear buds which have magnet inside them always attract but never repel?

Answer (score 0):

Good observation! I think this is probably because one pole of the speaker magnet is usually very near the outside housing, facing outwards. When the two However, the other pole is facing the "inside" of the earbuds.

```
]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]   [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
]]]]]]]]]]]+MMMMM-   +MMMMM-[[[[[[[[[[[[
]]]]]]]]]]]+MMMMM-   +MMMMM-[[[[[[[[[[[[
]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]   [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
```

The + pole and the - pole attract, but the other poles can never get near each other; + can't push against +, and - can't push against -.